# Is it true that Austrians who refused to help SS in catching Soviet POWs would not face any negative consequences?

Tags: world-war-two, ww2-european-theater, austria, prisoners-of-war

According to the [Viennese government](https://www.wien.gv.at/english/history/commemoration/mauthausen.html), civilians who refused to assist the [SS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schutzstaffel) in catching Soviet prisoners of war (during the [Mühlviertler Hasenjagd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%BChlviertler_Hasenjagd)) did not face any negative consequences (my emphasis):

> The hunt for the escapees also called for the assistance of the
> civilian population. And the people came and willingly obliged.
> According to the documents and the testimonies given by witnesses
> **there was no immediate threat to anyone nor was anyone forced to
> participate.** They did it all the same.

If it's true, you could simply refuse to cooperate with the [SS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schutzstaffel) and nothing bad would happen to you. Is there any hard evidence/support for this claim (apart from statements by eyewitnesses)?

Why, exactly, couldn't a [SS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schutzstaffel) officer shoot down some Austrian peasant who didn't want to chase the Soviets?

Comment: The phrase _The hunt for the escapees also called for the assistance of the civilian population_ sounds like they called for volunteers. From the rest of the paragraph, it sounds like they got the volunteers they needed, so the issue of '_Austrians who refused to help SS_ ...' probably never arose.

Comment: [Provide supporting evidence when you question the existing narrative](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/922/1401)

Comment: This question’s phrasing duplicates a number of denialist phrasings in English language. I am assuming this is unintentional and am offering to sub edit to a good faith version.

Comment: i think its a valid question and but @FranzDrollig there are other options than shooting people that they would perhaps have taken (against Volk) ? Fine, prison, public shaming spring to mind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard of real and genuine voluntarism, without consequence other than equivalent fatigue duties, in Jew and Slav hunting is well known and a commonplace in the scholarly literature. (Browning 1992 *Ordinary men*; Klee 1988 *The Good Old Days*). This holds for all theatres.

> If it's true, you could simply refuse to cooperate with the SS and nothing bad would happen to you.

Of course it isn’t true. Millions of Soviet Citizens and Polish Citizens discovered this.

> Why, exactly, couldn't a SS officer shoot down some Austrian peasant who didn't want to chase the Soviets?

Because they’re Volk.

Comment: What is "Volk"?

Comment: A German word used by German fascists.  It corresponds in some ways to the English "Folk."  It implies a national community centred on an agricultural experience which creates a blood-racial category.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volksgemeinschaft